# What can cause a unanimous review to be ignored?

Tags: support, review-queues

Yesterday [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/5305254) came into the LQP review queue and it was unanimously decided the post should be deleted as it isn't an answer.

It's mostly because there's no real question. They asked if the code they wrote would work (without trying it), the answer was basically "Yes" with some fluff. But 10 hours after the review ended its still there (unlike everything else I reviewed in yesterday's queue).

Is there something that's preventing the answer being deleted? Like perhaps a mod saw it and refused the delete? I suppose it's possible you could argue that it is an answer, but I don't think it's an appropriate question as there's no "[specific programming problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It was deleted, but later undeleted by the author. The revision history is not immediately accessible, but you can view it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24762335/revisions).

Posts that are deleted by review can be undeleted by their authors as a way to dispute the review.

Comment: Thanks for that, is there any further action to take? I was thinking about flagging the question but I wasn't sure if whoever read it would see the problem.

Comment: The author commented on the review to explain, so I've left a reply.

Comment: It should also be mentioned that moderators are flagged when this happens: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/228479/135615 so we know to remove true non-answers undeleted in this manner. Which tends to be most of them.