# Unanimous 'Unsalvageable' review, but question still open?

Tags: support, triage

I was perusing my review history (what a glutton for punishment, I know) and came across a Triage review from a few days ago.  I had deemed it 'Unsalvageable' (as off-topic, opinion-based ... if I remember correctly?).  Two other reviewers also deemed it 'Unsalvageable', and the review was completed unanimously.  However, the question is still open.

I've discovered that questions that are *deleted* by review can be undeleted by the author later (from [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265775/what-can-cause-a-unanimous-review-to-be-ignored) question), but that doesn't appear to be the case here (I looked at the edit history) ... plus I believe it would have been *closed* by review, not deleted by review.

The question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31413844/api-for-text-audio-and-video-in-ios). The review is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/8798431).

I'm just curious as to the mechanisms involved ... if Triage unanimously declares something Unsalvageable, shouldn't something have happened?

Comment: Maybe their edit caused the flags to be disputed? I'm baffled that someone with an account that old & that level of rep would ask a straight up recommendation question. Or maybe that's the issue; that not everyone chose the same close reason?

Comment: Can you post a link to the review?

Comment: @NathanOliver Did so.  I don't think I can see the other review reasons ....

Comment: if three people chose unsalvageable with a close reason, that would be three close votes, right? it takes 5 to close a question.

Comment: @KevinB I don't think so as they don't have the rep to cast close votes in this case.  I have seen that if you do have the rep to cast close votes that those votes stay no matter what the triage outcome is.

Comment: Right, in that case it would be close flags, as you suggest in answer, thus sending it into the close queue

Comment: related: [We should clean up posts that should be improved but haven't been and won't be](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/293457/839601)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

When a consensus is made questions that are marked as

- "Looks Ok" go to the homepage
- "Should be Improved" questions go to the help and improvement queue
- "Unsalvageable" questions go to the close/moderator flag queues.

Since none of reviewers that reviewed the question can cast close votes I would assume that the question entered the close vote queue with no close votes on it.  I have seen that if you do have the rep to cast close votes that those votes stay no matter what the triage outcome is.

Comment: Ahh, that makes all kinds of sense.  I suppose one should also give some time leeway to the back-logged close-vote queue.  I see the Meta effect has taken care of it, too.  It was the "it enters the close vote queue with no close votes" that I was missing.